# Android studio media player to play large size sounds

Tags: android, android-studio

My media player is with seekbar. Second seekbar is showing boot data from remote server. When the file size on the remote server is greater than 100 mb, some of it is reflected in the seekbar. Not all are loaded. What is the reason for this?

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    //mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).build());
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(Note: There is no problem with small files)

Comment: If you are playing sounds from server. I recommended you use `Exoplayer`. It plays faster then `mediaPlayer` and also handle big files. See here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer